# How do I make a button that adds a container with specific info inside in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Hello I'm still learning but cant find it for some reason,
My question is: I want to make a button that on press creates a new container and organizes it in a listview widget, how do I do that? do you have a tutorial or article about it that can help me?

Comment: Can you include your current code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Without example I would say the easier way would be to have an array with the widget you want in your listview, then on click add an element in your list with setState.

```
List<Widget> views = [Text("test"), Text("test2")];
```

then

```
ListView(children: views)
```

and final a function to call with your button

```
void addContainer()
{
  setState((){
     views.add(Container(color: Colors.red));
  });
}
```

I did not try it so it might contain some typos, but you get the logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list:

```
List<Widget> widgets = [
  widget1,
  widget2,
],
```

2. Change the `ListView`'s children to `widgets`:

```
ListView(
  children: widgets,
),
```

3. Make a button that when pressed creates a new `Container`:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    widgets.add(Container(child: child));
  },
  child: Text("Create a new container"),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize list of type Widget

```
List<Widget> widget=<Widget>[];
```

On Button Tap call the following method:

```
void addContainer(){
setState(() {
  widgetList.add(Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(height: 20,width: 30,color: Colors.red,),
  ));
});
```

}

Add Following code for create your list:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widgetList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return
        widgetList.isNotEmpty?
        widgetList.elementAt(index):SizedBox();
    },

  ),
```